# How to split the data inside the list and append to a new list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have data like this :

```
[
    {'dt': 1594533600, 'sys': {'pod': 'd'}, 'dt_txt': '2020-07-12 06:00:00'}, 
    {'dt': 1594544400, 'sys': {'pod': 'd'}, 'dt_txt': '2020-07-12 09:00:00'}, 
    {'dt': 1594555200, 'sys': {'pod': 'd'}, 'dt_txt': '2020-07-12 12:00:00'},
    {'dt': 1594566000, 'sys': {'pod': 'n'}, 'dt_txt': '2020-07-12 15:00:00'},
    {'dt': 1594576800, 'sys': {'pod': 'n'}, 'dt_txt': '2020-07-12 18:00:00'},
    {'dt': 1594587600, 'sys': {'pod': 'n'}, 'dt_txt': '2020-07-12 21:00:00'}, 
    {'dt': 1594598400, 'sys': {'pod': 'n'}, 'dt_txt': '2020-07-13 00:00:00'}, 
    {'dt': 1594609200, 'sys': {'pod': 'd'}, 'dt_txt': '2020-07-13 03:00:00'}, 
    {'dt': 1594620000, 'sys': {'pod': 'd'}, 'dt_txt': '2020-07-13 06:00:00'}, 
    {'dt': 1594630800, 'sys': {'pod': 'd'}, 'dt_txt': '2020-07-13 09:00:00'},
    {'dt': 1594641600, 'sys': {'pod': 'd'}, 'dt_txt': '2020-07-13 12:00:00'}, 
    {'dt': 1594652400, 'sys': {'pod': 'n'}, 'dt_txt': '2020-07-13 15:00:00'},
    {'dt': 1594663200, 'sys': {'pod': 'n'}, 'dt_txt': '2020-07-13 18:00:00'},
    {'dt': 1594674000, 'sys': {'pod': 'n'}, 'dt_txt': '2020-07-13 21:00:00'}
       ]
```

Expected output:

When I call this list I want the latest record of that **date(dt_text)**, like this:

```
     [ {'dt': 1594587600, 'sys': {'pod': 'n'}, 'dt_txt': '2020-07-12 21:00:00'},
       {'dt': 1594674000, 'sys': {'pod': 'n'}, 'dt_txt': '2020-07-13 21:00:00'}
      ]
```

I have tried to put all the date in one list and I have tried to sort but it didn't work. can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: why output contain two records only?

Comment: It has lot of records but for the reference, I have kept only two records, to see the full data please check here..

Comment: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=14.4426&lon=79.9865&appid=9e17b1086d0f65a15fc39bd0c39d9d51

Comment: can you explain how exactly are you getting output?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort (if not already sorted) and then use [itertools.groupby()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to get the groups. With that you can just take the first item of each group:

```
from itertools import groupby

s = sorted(l, key=lambda x: x['dt_txt'], reverse=True)  
top = [next(g) for k, g in groupby(s, key=lambda x: x['dt_txt'].split()[0] )]

print(top)
```

Prints:

```
[
 {'dt': 1594674000, 'sys': {'pod': 'n'}, 'dt_txt': '2020-07-13 21:00:00'}, 
 {'dt': 1594587600, 'sys': {'pod': 'n'}, 'dt_txt': '2020-07-12 21:00:00'}
]
```

Alternatively you can sort the other way and build a dict on the value you want to group by. The values will replace previous ones until you are left with the final value:

```
s = sorted(l, key=lambda x: x['dt_txt'])

d = {l['dt_txt'].split()[0]: l for l in s}

res = list(d.values())
```

res:

```
[{'dt': 1594587600, 'sys': {'pod': 'n'}, 'dt_txt': '2020-07-12 21:00:00'},
 {'dt': 1594674000, 'sys': {'pod': 'n'}, 'dt_txt': '2020-07-13 21:00:00'}]
```

This has the advantage of keeping the results in ascending order.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, say the starting list you provided is called `sample_list`. You can sort this list by time in `'dt_txt'` via:

```
import datetime

sorted(sample_list, key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x['dt_txt'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').time())
```

This will result in:

```
[{'dt': 1594598400, 'sys': {'pod': 'n'}, 'dt_txt': '2020-07-13 00:00:00'},
 {'dt': 1594609200, 'sys': {'pod': 'd'}, 'dt_txt': '2020-07-13 03:00:00'},
 {'dt': 1594533600, 'sys': {'pod': 'd'}, 'dt_txt': '2020-07-12 06:00:00'},
 {'dt': 1594620000, 'sys': {'pod': 'd'}, 'dt_txt': '2020-07-13 06:00:00'},
 {'dt': 1594544400, 'sys': {'pod': 'd'}, 'dt_txt': '2020-07-12 09:00:00'},
 {'dt': 1594630800, 'sys': {'pod': 'd'}, 'dt_txt': '2020-07-13 09:00:00'},
 {'dt': 1594555200, 'sys': {'pod': 'd'}, 'dt_txt': '2020-07-12 12:00:00'},
 {'dt': 1594641600, 'sys': {'pod': 'd'}, 'dt_txt': '2020-07-13 12:00:00'},
 {'dt': 1594566000, 'sys': {'pod': 'n'}, 'dt_txt': '2020-07-12 15:00:00'},
 {'dt': 1594652400, 'sys': {'pod': 'n'}, 'dt_txt': '2020-07-13 15:00:00'},
 {'dt': 1594576800, 'sys': {'pod': 'n'}, 'dt_txt': '2020-07-12 18:00:00'},
 {'dt': 1594663200, 'sys': {'pod': 'n'}, 'dt_txt': '2020-07-13 18:00:00'},
 {'dt': 1594587600, 'sys': {'pod': 'n'}, 'dt_txt': '2020-07-12 21:00:00'},
 {'dt': 1594674000, 'sys': {'pod': 'n'}, 'dt_txt': '2020-07-13 21:00:00'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that `data` is already sorted by the `dt` key.

```py
def latest_only(data):
    # accumulate the last entry for each day in latest_only_data
    latest_only_data = []
    last_date = data[0]['dt_txt'].split()[0]
    for i, d in enumerate(data[1:]):
        new_date = d['dt_txt'].split()[0]
        if last_date != new_date:
            # The enumerate is starting from the second entry so it would actually
            #  be i-1 for the index into the full `data`.
            # We want the last entry which is one less than the current index, which is 
            #  what enumerate is already giving us!
            latest_only_data.append(data[i])

            last_date = new_date

    latest_only_data.append(data[-1])

    return latest_only_data
```

Which outputs:

```
[{'dt': 1594587600, 'dt_txt': '2020-07-12 21:00:00', 'sys': {'pod': 'n'}},
 {'dt': 1594674000, 'dt_txt': '2020-07-13 21:00:00', 'sys': {'pod': 'n'}}]
```